# Installing npm on WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Laravel application that needs sass/scss.

I'm trying to install NPM using `npm install` but it keeps telling me

> npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

> npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

> npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin

> npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined

> npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux

> npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

I'm using the latest Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. I've tried several attempts to solve this by:

1. Reinstalling Node and NPM
2. Changing the owner of the folder (laravel folder) to me

Any advice?

Comment: I tried using NVM as well, and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Removed $PATH from Windows Local Environment Path as well

Answer (score 0):

1. run `npm audit fix` and see if you can successfully follow the given
   advice to resolve all "high severity vulnerability" issues
2. Remove the local `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`
3. Clean npm cache by `npm cache verify`
4. Update the global npm by `sudo npm i -g npm`
5. Reinstall the local node_modules by `npm install`

Comment: `npm audit fix` doesn't work, gives me an ENOLOCK error.

In addition, `npm install` gives the same error with EBADPLATFORM

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has to do with using WSL 2, since in Ubuntu it shouldn't cause any trouble.
You could try `npm i fsevents --force`. That way it will disable the recommended protections and install it anyway.